# How to print \n in a String in java

Tags: java

I want to print \n.

```
String text = "";

text = "\n is used for new line";
```

but the \n is not showing when I run the code. How to do this?

Comment: If you're planning on writing to the console, rather than using "print" use "println".  That will give you your linebreak anyway.

Answer (score 11):

Escape the `\` with `\`

```
text = "\\n is used for new line";
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to actually write the two chars `\`and `n` to output, you need to escape the backslash: `\\n`.

All escape sequences are listed in the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `System.lineSeparator()`, introduced in **Java 8**:

```
String result = "cat" + System.lineSeparator() + "dog";
System.out.print(result);
```

Output:

```
cat
dog
```

Comment: I repealed the downvote, but the downvote was originally because you missed the point of the OP's question.  They don't want to print a newline char.  They want to print the literal '\n' char.

Comment: In deed, I totally missed that part. Thanks for the clarification !

Answer (score 3):

In java, the `\` char is an escape character, meaning that the following char is some sort of control character (such as \n \t or \r).

**To print literals in Java escape it with an additional `\` char**

Such as:

```
String text = "\\n is used for a new line";
System.out.println(text);
```

Will print:

> \n is used for a new line