# How to show "\n" as text in Eclipse?

Tags: java

The question is same as the title.

Is it possible to show \n in the text without its function ?

I've tried several ways but I couldn't. 
It wouldn't be really necessary but I'm just curious.

Thank you !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724850/how-to-print-n-in-a-string-in-java/33724875

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have example:

```
System.out.println("1234\\n5678");
```

Comment: Thank you, that just helped me perfectly !